# Playing external sound (song saved in the tablet) in as3 AIR (android app)

Tags: actionscript-3, air, playback

I'm developing an android app using adobe flash AIR. I want to play a song, which stored in the tablet (eg.My files/music/sample.mp3). How to get this data from the tablet?

```
myChannel = new SoundChannel();
mySound = new Sound();
mySound.load(new URLRequest("My files/music/sample.mp3"));
myChannel = mySound.play();
```

Comment: Well if you know the directory then whats the problem? Also only do that  `mySound.play();` in a load complete event. Like in **[this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14741890/2057709)** you need a `mySound.addEventlistener...etc...` then in your own `loadComplete` just try put there the line `myChannel = mySound.play();`. This is needed because your code could reach `play()` command before Android OS even gave your app permission to access that file so it fails...

Comment: PS: Using a file manager app, what does it say about the **full mp3 url** on your SD card? Does your code have exact same url? Also If that space in file path `My files` is a problem then use `File` instead. See **[this guide](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fe4.html)**. First try creating a simple directory called **Test** in SD card root then just load mp3 from there. Does it work? if not then use `File` class as per linked guide. I can only guess cos not enough info about your problem. Are you checking that your code can tell you the file exists?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this option, but song is not playing.

Comment: I copied a 'test.mp3' in the tablet Music folder . I checked the URL using filemanager. the basic flow of the code is 

var sound:Sound = new Sound();
var soundChannel:SoundChannel;
sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onMp3LoadComplete);
sound.load(new URLRequest("Music/test.mp3"));

function onMp3LoadComplete(e:Event):void
{
    sound.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onMp3LoadComplete);
    soundChannel = sound.play();
}

Comment: If you have `"Music/test.mp3"` then your app expects to find a subfolder called Music to exist in whatever directory its running from (ie: the OS Installed Apps folder). So that won't work. If you make a new folder in "internal storage" (root) called "myTest" then the path should be `/storage/emulated/0/myTest/test.mp3`. Test it. From there you can try moving it your music folder and work out the path logic. PS: There are free APKs of file managers to create new folder at root level (don't assume built-in is best, the external apps exist to surpass limitations)

Comment: Is this solved now..?